# Reference controller which is inside a module

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller defined inside a module:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.property = 'myproperty'; });
```

A partial is included in the main html like this:

```
<div ng-include src="'partial/mypartial.html'"></div>
```

Is it possible to reference MyCtrl inside mypartial.html? e.g. somehow like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myModule.MyCtrl">
```

Thanks!

Comment: if 'myModule' is your top level module (ng-app) then you can just reference the controller as "MyCtrl". I think it should work like that even if you are using a submodule (as long as you passed it as a dependency to your main module)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I had to pass my submodule as a dependecy to the main module

Answer (score 1):

Given the angular javascript:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.property = 'myproperty'; });
```

Your view setup should look something like:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{property}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code should generate:

```
myproperty
```