# how to reference a controller inside a sub-module in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I'm using modules /sub modules on the angular app, my **controller doesn't load** on a specific route but the view does, according to a comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558890/reference-controller-which-is-inside-a-module) I should reference the child module inside the main module and that should do the trick.

this is my code for bootstrapping the app:

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ui.router', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'facebook', 'subModule1', 'subModule2', 'subModule3']);

angular.module('mainApp').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, FacebookProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("root",
    {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'footer@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/footer/footer.html",

            },
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/header/header.html",
            }
        }
    }).state('root.home', {
        url: '/index',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: '/partial/index/index.html',
                controller: 'IndexCtrl'
                }
            },
        }
    ).state('root.login', {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: '/partial/login/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            }
        },
    });
    FacebookProvider.init('xxxxxx');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
});
```

I have the sub-module configuration in a separate folder named **/subModule1/submodule1.js**

```
angular.module('subModule1').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("submodule1",
    {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'footer@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/footer/footer.html",

            },
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/header/header.html",
            }
        }
    }).state('submodule1.dashboard',
    {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: '/subModule1/partial/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    dashboardinfo: function($resource) {
                        var resourceGet = $resource('/submodule1/dashboard');
                        return resourceGet.get().$promise;
                    }
                }
            },
            'sideBar@': {
                templateUrl: '/submodule1/partial/sidebar/sidebar.html'
            },
            'navBar@': {
                templateUrl: '/submodule1/partial/navbar/navbar.html'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the controller is defined as:

```
angular.module('subModule1').controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $interval, $resource, notification, dashboardinfo) { ... }
```

the index located on the root of the page which is the page layout have the

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
```

and the controller have the ng-controller definiton  as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
```

Everything is fine just the controller isn't running, it doesn't get executed by the view.

Comment: Have you tried this - controller: 'submodule1.DashboardCtrl',

Comment: I tried and I get [ng:areq] Argument 'submodule1.DashboardCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ui-router` and `ng-controller="DashboardCtrl"` are intended to work together. In the `ui-router` world we are assigning `Controllers` to `views` directly in the state definition.

So this *(exactly as you have already have it, no change)* is enough:

```
.state('submodule1.dashboard',
{
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
        'container@': {
            templateUrl: '/subModule1/partial/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
```

to say, that the view rendered inside of the `ui-view="container"` on the root *(index.html)* should be provided with `DashboardCtrl`.

There is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xV09iV1UVzWEDMnquKPM?p=preview) using the above state definition *(1:1 as possible)*.

This is the index.html content:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="navBar"></div>
<div ui-view="container"></div>
<div ui-view="sideBar"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

And this links will correctly trigger the above states:

```
// root
<li><a ui-sref="root.home">root.home</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="root.login">root.login</a></li>

// dashboard
<li><a ui-sref="submodule1.dashboard">submodule1.dashboard</a></li>
```

All the other details check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xV09iV1UVzWEDMnquKPM?p=preview)

Comment: turns out that I got two files named dashboardCtrl in to different modules, it seems like that were causing the issue, but your answer lead me to my conclusion, so thanks

Comment: Great to see that, also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14909537/1679310 ... Service (including Ctrl) naming is fragile thing ;) good luck with angular;)